# WPF DataGrid стиль ячеек в зависимости от значения

Tags: wpf, wpf-datagrid

в инете нашел способ для только для столбца, если их много то в каждом писать такой блок:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

как то некрасиво. 
пишу так:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

--> Член "Text" не распознан или недоступен"

как задать триггер для всех ячеек сразу?

Comment: Вынесите стиль в ресурсы и указывайте его в столбцах

Comment: Получилось? Как вариант, можно написать наследника класса `DataGridTextColumn` с переопределенным стилем элемента